# What is the sum of the first 21 numbers of the formula below?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I know how to solve the geometric progression and arithmetic progression but this one seems strange to me, it isn't even a harmonic serie, Any help for solving it would be appreciated.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{21}\frac{3n+1}{n^{n+1}}$$

I have simplified the formula to this:

$\frac{3n}{n^{n+1}}$  --> $\frac{3}{n^{n}}$  --> $3\frac{1}{n^{n}}$

and $\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}$
so it would be:

$3\frac{1}{n^{n}}$ + $\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}$

I there would be a formula for calculating the sum of $\frac{1}{n^{n}}$ the problem would have been solved.

Comment: Please add your tries on problem so other do new think or resume your works.

Answer (score 0):

$$a(n)=\frac{3n+1}{n^{n+1}};$$
by direct evaluation:
\begin{align}
a(1)&=4,\\
a(2)&=\frac{7}{8},\\
a(3)&=\frac{10}{81},\\
a(4)&=\frac{13}{1024},\\
a(5)&=\frac{16}{15625},\\
a(6)&=\frac{19}{279936},\\
a(7)&=\frac{22}{5764801},\\
a(8)&=\frac{25}{134217728},\\
a(9)&=\frac{28}{3486784401},\\
a(10)&=\frac{31}{100000000000},\\
a(11)&=\frac{34}{3138428376721},\\
a(12)&=\frac{37}{106993205379072},\\
a(13)&=\frac{40}{3937376385699289},\\
a(14)&=\frac{43}{155568095557812224},\\
a(15)&=\frac{46}{6568408355712890625},\\
a(16)&=\frac{49}{295147905179352825856},\\
a(17)&=\frac{52}{14063084452067724991009},\\
a(18)&=\frac{55}{708235345355337676357632},\\
a(19)&=\frac{58}{37589973457545958193355601},\\
a(20)&=\frac{61}{2097152000000000000000000000},\\
a(21)&=\frac{64}{122694327386105632949003612841};
\end{align}
and thus
$$\sum_{n=1}^{21}a(n)=$$$$=\frac{24337651273862904342162074151785982994279099497679049814305735315835173341887671747940629210170039412260460824380065531633950247166152561878023227749}{4855635902506538513811470432057980704810800085167684813453025052382052387055783651601498359417802752146253089501466328215584768000000000000000000000}\approx$$$$\approx5.01225.$$